# How to export 2 arrow functions on react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this file

```
const validateIfDataExist = value => (value === null ? 'N/A' : value);

const removeNumbersFromAString = value => value.replace(/[^a-z]/gi, '');

export { validateIfDataExist, removeNumbersFromAString };
```

And I am trying to call here one of the modules:

`import removeNumbersFromAString from '../../utils/validation-utils';`

But I am getting an error when I try to import it:

> Default export is not declared in imported module

So, why should I set `export default` ?

Answer (score 3):

Since you didn't use a `default` export:

`export default removeNumbersFromAString;`

you will have to use a named import instead.

```
import { removeNumbersFromAString } from '../../utils/validation-utils';
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax that you're using assumes that you're trying to import the default export from `../../utils/validation-utils`.

### To Get it working with what you have

```
import { removeNumbersFromAString } from '../../utils/validation-utils';
```

This will pull the named exports from that file. You've exposed `validateIfDataExist` and `removeNumbersFromAString` by exporting them the way you have it.

### What the error is telling you

It seems like you understand this, but I think it's fair to bring up. You can export a default constant or function from a file by doing this:

```
export default function validateIfDataExist(value) {
  return value === null ? 'N/A' : value;
}
```

Then with the import statement that you can choose to either keep the same name or rename it for your purposes in the importing file.

```
import removeNumbersFromAString from '../../utils/validation-utils';
```

or

```
import somethingTotallyDifferent from '../../utils/validation-utils';
```

both work the exact same, importing the default function and casting it to the variable.

### Everything operator (*)

As a total aside to that aside, this would also work with what you've got

```
import * as validations from '../../utils/validation-utils';

validations.removeNumbersFromAString(string);
validations.validateIfDataExist(data);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can change your imports like this:

```
export const validateIfDataExist = value => (value === null ? 'N/A' : value);

export const removeNumbersFromAString = value => value.replace(/[^a-z]/gi, '');

export default { validateIfDataExist, removeNumbersFromAString };
```

There you have an example of how to export everything, maybe you don't need to export it all, but you can decide. Now, to import you can:

```
import { removeNumbersFromAString, validateIfDataExist } from '../../utils/validation-utils';
```

or

```
import validationUtils from '../../utils/validation-utils';
const { validateIfDataExist, removeNumbersFromAString } = validationUtils;
```

Export just what you want instead of the default is a better approach to avoid include unnecessary and heavy libraries on your component, But you can do both

Hope this helps you!

Comment: The `default` keyword in your first example is redundant, because it still has to be imported separately.

Comment: The importation example just shows how you can export everything, he just needs to figure out which fits better.

Comment: Yet still `default` keyword isn't used properly.